# java inheritance and polymorphism

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

this is my first question here so please apologize if I do mistakes.
Trying to better understand oop (inheritance, polymorphism, abstractization) I have imagine the following exercise : in a JPanel with BorderLayout I add a JPanel which contains two JRadioButton and an abstract panel that extends JPanel. The abstract panel can point to 2 different concrete children ... but it doesn't work as I expected. . When I select the rectangle button on the console is printed "rectangle fires event" but the paint Component of the rectangle object is not executed and when I select the oval button on the console is printed "oval fires event" and "paint oval draw oval" which means the paint Component of the oval button is executed. Please help me to understand what do I do wrong? Why the paintComponent of the rectangle is not executed?
I repeat, my aim is to practice and understand oop, not to draw ovals and rectangles.
Here is my code

```
public class MyGeometry extends JPanel{
private MyShape shape;
private JPanel shapeControl = new JPanel();
private JRadioButton rbtOval = new JRadioButton("Oval");
private JRadioButton rbtRectangle = new JRadioButton("Rectangle");

MyGeometry(){
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    // setting radio buttons
    ButtonGroup shapeButton = new ButtonGroup();
    shapeButton.add(rbtOval);
    shapeButton.add(rbtRectangle);
    rbtOval.setSelected(true);
    shapeControl.add(rbtOval);
    shapeControl.add(rbtRectangle);

    //Initialize shape to avoid null pointer exception
    final MyOval oval = new MyOval();
    final MyRectangle rectangle = new MyRectangle();
    shape = oval;

    //add components to the panel
    add(shapeControl, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(shape);

    //add event handling
    rbtOval.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            shape = oval;
            shape.repaint();
            System.out.println("Oval fires event");
        }
    });
    rbtRectangle.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            shape = rectangle;
            shape.repaint();
            System.out.println("Rectangle fires event");
        }
    });
}


public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
    return new Dimension(500, 500);
}

public abstract class MyShape extends JPanel{
    public abstract String dummyString();
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
}
public class MyOval extends MyShape{
    public String dummyString(){
        return "Draw oval";
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawOval(50, 50, 100, 80);
        String textOval = "paint oval " + dummyString();
        System.out.println(textOval);
    }
}
public class MyRectangle extends MyShape{
    public String dummyString(){
        return "Draw rectangle";
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawRect(50, 50, 100, 80);
        String textRectangle = "paint rectangle " + dummyString();
        System.out.println(textRectangle);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If your goal is to learn object oriented design in java (including polymorphism and inheritance)  i would read Java Concepts: Early Objects by Cay Horstmann

Comment: It's much easier to read a post that is broken up into thoughts/ideas. When things are easier to read it's easier to get help.

Answer (score 0):

> the paint Component of the rectangle object is not executed

All you are doing is setting a field on the JPanel, you are not changing the JPanel itself.  I suspect what you intended was to remove the oval and add the rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Your OOP is sound; your Swing is not.

You started off with `shape` set to your `oval`. This shape was added to your JPanel. The rectangle was never added to the JPanel. Even when you set `shape = rectangle`, and then tell it to draw, Swing knows that your `rectangle` has no parent component, and thus will never be drawn. So telling it to `repaint()` will **not** call `paintComponent()`.